# How can I add an specific icon to this CV template?

Tags: hyperref, symbols, moderncv, links

How can I add the [dblp](http://dblp.uni-trier.de/) logo to a [cv](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/cv-or-resume/moderncv-banking)?. For instance as this type of symbols:

[image]

Any idea of how to approach this?.

Comment: How do you get this logo? Abd where would you like to put it on the cv?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`moderncv` stores its symbols in a bunch of makros that you can redefine:

```
\renewcommand*{\addresssymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\homepagesymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol}{}
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}{}
```

See `moderncviconsmarvosym.sty` on the `moderncv` [repository in CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv).

Here is what it could look like by picking out the twitter field:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman]{moderncv} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}       
\moderncvstyle{banking}     
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\newcommand{\dblp}[1]{\collectionadd[twitter]{socials}{\protect\httplink[#1]{dblp.uni-trier.de/search?q=#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol}{%
    \raisebox{-0.08em}{%
    \scalebox{0.7}{%
        \tikz{\draw node[rectangle, rounded corners, draw=color2, inner sep=1pt] (0,0) {\textsf{dblp}};}~% 
    }}}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resumé title}  
\address{street and number}{postcode city}{country}
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}                   
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}                    
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      
\email{john@doe.org}                               
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                      
\dblp{doe:john}  

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Could you provide some example?, I review the documentation but still dont get how to proceed. Thanks

Comment: @skwoi: I've added an example.

Answer (score 4):

Just add these lines to your preamble (`logodblp.png` is the name of the logo graphic file):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\pretocmd{\makecvtitle}{\leavevmode\vskip-40pt{\includegraphics[scale = 0.33]{logodblp}}\vskip20pt}{}{}
```

[image]

If you want to add the `dblp logo` to the `additional information` item, say, just add these lines to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand*{\extrainfosymbol}{\includegraphics[scale = 0.05]{logodblp}}
\patchcmd{\extrainfo}{#1}{\extrainfosymbol~#1}{}{}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the support. I was thinking in something like the little symbols below the Resumé title e.g. telephone, mobile, web page, aditional information,etc (in black).

Comment: @skwoi: I've just added the small code to do that.